# Finding $\int\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\cos(2\sqrt{x+5})}}}}{\sqrt{x}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

The following integral is well posed? we must correct?

$$\int\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\cos(2\sqrt{x+5})}}}}{\sqrt{x}}dx$$

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: A change of variable $y = 2\sqrt{x+5}, dy = \frac{dx}{\sqrt x}$ converts this integral into a simpler form, and W|A says that a closed form solution does not exist.

Comment: There is no issue about the function we are integrating, if $x$ is positive. Nice and continuous, so there is an antiderivative. I would be very surprised if the antiderivative could be expressed in terms of elementary functions, but have no proof that it cannot be so expressed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the OP means by 'well posed'. It's an indefinite integral, so there is no question about convergence.

As for the antiderivative, it exists, but most likely can't be found in closed form, as it was said in the comments.

However, we can simplify the integral a little.

First, make a change of variable:

$$y=\sqrt{x+5}$$

$$x=y^2-5$$

$$dx=2y~dy$$

Then we obtain

$$2 \int \sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\cos(2y)}}} \frac{y ~dy}{\sqrt{y^2-5}}$$

Now use the double angle formula:

$$|\cos y| = \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos 2y}{2}}$$

We get:

$$2 \int \sqrt{1+\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2} |\cos y|}} \frac{y ~dy}{\sqrt{y^2-5}}$$

Here $||$ denotes absolute value. We got rid of one of the nested roots. I don't think we can simplify it any further.

Comment: That hardly answers the question . can you edit so i can see how it helps.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar, the OP stated that any hint would be appreciated. Since the most problematic part is the nested root, I gave a way to make this nested root a little simpler. It's likely there is no closed form